# How to draw a line with itextsharp if line "---"?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, itext

I write a code with Visual Studio 2005 C# 2.0 Net. I read a Textfile and the content of Textfile in a PDF-File. Now I want to Replace the Text ("---") from Textfile with draw line.

```
public void PDFCreate()
{
   iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 10, 40, 40);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);


    ///########
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\WINNT\Fonts\COUR.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    iTextSharp.text.Font f = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);

    BaseFont bs = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\WINNT\Fonts\COUR.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    iTextSharp.text.Font s = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bs, 10.2f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

    doc.Open();

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

    string myfiles = MySetIniPath + feld[0] + "_rus." + feld[1];
    string str;
    StreamReader myfi = new StreamReader(myfiles);
    {
        while ((str = myfi.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (str.Contains("MIMO"))
                doc.NewPage();

            if (str != "")
            {
                if (str.StartsWith("результат теста"))
                {
                    doc.Add(new Phrase(str, s));
                    doc.Add(new Phrase("\n\n", s));
                    continue;
                }
                if (str.StartsWith("Nummer"))
                {
                    doc.Add(new Phrase(str, f));
                    doc.Add(new Phrase("\n\n", f));
                    continue;
                }
                if (str.StartsWith("MIMO") ||
                    str.StartsWith("Serial") ||
                    str.StartsWith("Numbers") ||
                    str.StartsWith("order"))
                {
                    doc.Add(new Phrase(str + "\n", f));
                    continue;
                }
                if (str.StartsWith("---"))
                {
                    //Draw a line
                    continue;
                }
                doc.Add(new Phrase(str + "\n", s));
            }
        }
    }
    doc.Close();
    myfi.Close();
}
```

How can I write(REPLACE) `if(str.StartsWith("----"))` draw a line with using itextsharp or with `e.Graphics.MeasureString(" ", boldFont)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Replace and DrawString

```
var text = "----- other text";
var yourValue =e.Graphics.DrawString();//Adjust your drawstring
var result = text.Replace("-----", yourValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the solution:

```
  if (str.IndexOf("|") > -1)
  {
       char vertLine = '\u2502'; 
       str = str.Replace("|", vertLine.ToString());
       doc.Add(new Phrase(str + "\n", s));

       continue;
    }

    if (str.StartsWith("---"))
    {  
         char vert = '\u2500'; 
         str = str.Replace("--", vert.ToString());
         doc.Add(new Phrase(str + str +"\n", s));

          continue;
      }
```